# Backup and restore only some partitions

Tags: partition, backup

I have a system which runs an arcade machine. It has the regular swap and root partitions, but then I have an extra partition which I call data. Data holds many gigabytes of game content.

The idea is that if anything goes wrong with the Linux system, I should be able to restore it from a backup and leave `/data` intact.

My question is, what utility is best to backup and restore just the Linux system partitions? Can I just use `dd` to make an image of `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`, for example? What about the MBR - Master Boot Record?

Comment: `rsync` is good. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_system_backup_with_rsync

Comment: What if a partition becomes corrupt somehow? From what I understand rsync is a fancy copy+paste tool.

Comment: `rsync` is used to preserve the user permissions and other things as well which is why it is more better than copy + paste. From what I believe, you just want your system to be up immediately if it is crashing. You might want to have a script that automatically backs up the root partition to an external HDD. Then when the system crashes, you can restore it from the external HDD.

Comment: You might want to look into this question as well. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114804/backup-server-users-creation

Comment: Also take a look at this one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41399/system-image-of-running-debian-system

Comment: BTW, what's the distro?

Answer (score 1):

For simple copying, using `rsync` to copy to your backup medium, as mentioned in the comments, is sufficient.  If you want versioned backups and easier control, [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org/) is a good choice.

However, for a system partition, there's often an easier option.  Since most of the data comes unmodified from your distro's repositories, you can usually manage by simply backing up `/etc`, `/var`, and the list of installed packages (which is probably in `/var`).

Note that none of this will back up the MBR, but on a Linux system, MBR corruption usually results from a failed hard drive.